# Transformation of dependent variable for MARS algorithm?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, nonparametric, mars

I am just wondering if its necessary to transform a dependent variable as it is a large monetary value? I'm unsure if its necessary with a non-parametric methods such as MARS. When I do a log transformation my Rsq value is improved, is this indicative of a worthy transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of MARS in terms of $R^2$ is theoretically independent of *linear* changes in scale.  I frequently use MARS to model potentially large monetary values, and in my experience the log transformation, or Box-Cox or whatever, can be essential to prevent over-fitting.  (This is not a contradiction, since such transformations are nonlinear, which is why they work).  However, an improvement in $R^2$ (especially if on the training set) is not necessarily an indication of that the log model is better.  In fact, there is not a simple relationship between $R^2$ as computed on the original scale and $R^2$ on a log scale.  When comparing predictive models across nonlinear monotonic transformations, you should use order-based statistics such as Spearman's rank correlation coefficient, which are fixed under such transformations.

Finally, as you may be aware, you can't transform your predictions on the log scale back to the original data scale simply by inverting the log transformation.  In general you'll probably need to fit some kind of nonlinear univariate monotone function to get back to monetary scale.